# Eclipse cannot resolve to a type after import

Tags: java, eclipse, import

Newbie question here...I've wrote an application in eclipse and I've added to a private github repo.  I went to import the application to a new workspace so I can work out of my github location and not have to constantly copy/paste.  When I import the working application as an existing project into Eclipse, everything I've imported gets hit with a "cannot be resolved" error.

I was wondering if their is something I could do to resolve this?

Comment: We can't really help you without any source code. Could you please edit your question and add the source code that is causing the problem?

Comment: I could, but it really isn't relevent I don't think.  It's an eclipse created EJB project in which I've just imported the same working project, libs and all, as a new project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens sometimes with Eclipse.  Try to clean your project(Project -> Clean).  If that doesnt work restart Eclipse.

Another reason could be that you don't have the necessary jar files for your imports.  If this is the case then import the jars(Right Click Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add External Jars).

Comment: Also checking the "Build Automatic" option (Project --> Build Automatically) can be helpful. And if none of that works it might be the classpath (Package explorer --> Plug-in tools --> Update classpath)

Comment: Looks like I forgot to add the wildfly runtime to the project.  Forgot about that :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use gradle as the build tool, just run gradle eclipse

Answer (score 0):

When this happens for a single class I used to Ctrl+click on the class (Open Declaration).
Cut the contents. Save it.
Paste the contents back. Save it again.